# (inverter repairs) Does reverse polarity can kill power MOSFETs in UPS inverters?

Tags: power-supply, inverter, ups, powermosfet

I had an old computer UPS (almost 7 years) and I modified it to use external battery (a 12 Volt motorcycle battery) since the old 12 Volt battery is completely dead and no replacement is available for sale for the same model.

So far, I used the UPS with the new battery for almost 1 year and it worked fine, until I did a maintenance and voltage checks. I disconnected the battery during the process, but this is where things get screwed up.

I accidentally connected the battery backwards (I didn't notice the battery polarity markings because it's just embossed on the black plastic surface and there's no color markings, and I worked in the nighttime lighting.)

There was just a small spark from the battery terminals where I touched the battery cables and nothing more (no smoke, explosions or whatever) Everything works fine except for the inverter part of the UPS is not working and there's no output voltage (there's just one small voltage pulse on the output where the inverter is supposed to turn on, I checked it with a 5 Volt USB LED light connected to a phone charger plugged into the inverter output).

The indicator LEDs and the buzzer works fine. (I tried powering it both from the battery and mains input). The circuit seems doesn't have any reverse polarity protection (Because it seems unnecessary as the battery replacements and repairs have to be "done by professionals" as the manual says) and there's no fuse for the battery side.

There's only one fuse for the mains input but it's still good and it has nothing to do with my problem here. There are possibilities that the reverse polarity killed the power MOSFETs (it has two SW3205 MOSFETs) or the oscillator/controller circuit (it has 3 LM339 comparators and 1 SG3524N possibly for signal generator) There's also a voltage regulator (UTC317) possibly for powering the oscillator and control circuit.

Any chance that one (or more) of them are killed by the reverse polarity? (I don't know about the MOSFETs, whether they can be killed by 12 Volt reverse voltage or they're supposed to take that much power since it's a high power component).

If there's any chance for repairs, I want to give it a shot repairing it but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Without schematics (I recommend some reverse-engineering on your part) It could depend on the topology but in general a reverse polarity will flow through the body diodes on all the FETs, and without current limitation these will go up in smoke.

If the designers didn’t implement any reverse polarity protection, every single IC on the circuit became a forward-biased diode, if you are lucky only the regulator blew-up in this condition. . But the FETs will probably connect directly to the battery through the low-impedance windings of a transformer.

I am not sure of what standards apply to the battery side of an UPS, but I would consider not having some sort of fuse/breaker for the battery connection rather unsafe. Given that you did not see any physical damage or smoke, it is very likely that there is a fuse on the PCB that you have not recognized.